# Push service not registering on blackberry curve

Tags: blackberry, push, blackberry-jde, curve

For some reason i keep getting a PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_NOT_REGISTERED when i try to register for push services on blackberry curve. It works great on the torch, storm, but having so much problem on the bold and curve.

Here's the code on how i register for push services:

```
int port = Constant.Net.PUSH_PORT;
    String appId = Constant.Net.APP_PUSH_ID;
    String bpasUrl = Constant.Net.BPAS_URL;
    ApplicationDescriptor ad = ApplicationDescriptor.currentApplicationDescriptor();
    byte serverType = PushApplicationDescriptor.SERVER_TYPE_BPAS;

    PushApplicationDescriptor pad = new PushApplicationDescriptor(appId, port, bpasUrl, serverType, ad);
    PushApplicationStatus status = PushApplicationRegistry.getStatus(pad);
    byte bstatus = status.getStatus();

    if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_ACTIVE)
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: already registered");
        AlertDialog.alert(LH.getString(LH.LBL_PUSH_REGISTERED));
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_PENDING)
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: status pending");
        AlertDialog.alert(LH.getString(LH.LBL_PUSH_REGISTERED));
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.REASON_REJECTED_BY_SERVER )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: rejected by server");
        AlertDialog.alert("REASON_REJECTED_BY_SERVER");
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.REASON_INVALID_PARAMETERS )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: REASON_INVALID_PARAMETERS");
        AlertDialog.alert("REASON_INVALID_PARAMETERS");
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.REASON_SIM_CHANGE )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: REASON_SIM_CHANGE");
        AlertDialog.alert("REASON_SIM_CHANGE");
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.REASON_NETWORK_ERROR )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: REASON_NETWORK_ERROR");
        AlertDialog.alert("REASON_NETWORK_ERROR");
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.REASON_API_CALL )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: REASON_API_CALL");
        AlertDialog.alert("REASON_API_CALL");
        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_NOT_REGISTERED )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: Status not registered");
        AlertDialog.alert("STATUS_NOT_REGISTERED");

        return;
    }
    else if (bstatus == PushApplicationStatus.STATUS_FAILED )
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: Status failed");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        L.devout("BpasProtocol: scheduling registration");

        PushApplicationRegistry.registerApplication(pad);
        AlertDialog.alert(LH.getString(LH.LBL_PUSH_REGISTERED));
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated since it takes forever to get any response from RIM.

Answer (score 0):

PushApplicationStatus.getStatus() returns one of STATUS_PENDING, STATUS_ACTIVE, STATUS_FAILED or STATUS_NOT_REGISTERED.

I don't think you should compare this status value with any of the REASON_* constants.

Also if the status is STATUS_NOT_REGISTERED then you should attempt to register your application! Your code does the registration in the else-branch, which should never be reached since one of the four STATUS_* values should have matched.

Take a look at the sample-push-enabled-app that comes with the BlackBerry Push Service SDK. You'll find the complete source code in a jar file: sample-push-enabled-app-1.0.1.11-sources.jar